# Copy mode in Excel stays active

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

When you copy in Excel, the cell gets highlight. And when you edit any other cell, it gets back to normal and you can't paste anymore. But for me, the cell stays highlight and I still can paste it.

For VBA user : CutCopyMode won't go to False as it should when I edit any other cell.

I have the same behavior with cut.

It's annoying as I have a bunch of cells which stays highlighted. How can I bring back the normal way Excel works?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the meaning of your "*For VBA user:*" note? Are you working with VBA while you are having these issues?

Comment: No I'm not using VBA at this time. It's just a different explanation for the same problem. It seems more clear for me this way.

Comment: Does this problem happen in all workbooks? Or only certain ones?

Comment: All workbook. It started like 2 weeks ago. I did not change anything in my PC

Comment: I would love to have that behavior. Be sure to post the reason when you find it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-5fdb9208-ff33-45b6-9e08-1f5cdb3a6c73?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

See the release notes for May 2017 'Keep the Copy'. A really annoying 'feature' and looks like no way to disable yet.

Comment: You might consider adding further quoted reference from the content of the links you provided in case the links ever go bad, the content will still be on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting the "Esc" key should remove the copy/cut selection around those cells.

Closing and reopening Excel should work if this issue persists.

Comment: I'm not looking for a workaround but a solution to bring back the normal excel behavior

Comment: Perhaps there is a setting that has been altered by an add-in, update, etc. I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling Excel. A fresh installation will have all the default settings and stop highlighting the cells.

Answer (score 0):

It's a new feature in the last Office 365 update. It seems there's no way to go back for now.

Comment: Do you have documentation of this?

Comment: I did not find documentation to back this, but I delete and reinstall the software without any changes and I check with other O365 users and they have this new behavior in Excel

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems like something that happened in the latest update. Had to set cutcopymode to false in a bunch of my macros. Pretty annoying.

Comment: Your answer is like a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Confirm it is still present in the latest Excel 365.

You need to press Esc, or press Enter instead of using mouse.

Although I see the potential benefit, I also find it confusing and annoying. Moreover, if you insert cells then hit F4 (redo) it will repeat the insert BUT it will also paste the copied cell if it is still active.

So, unless Microsoft adds a possibility to turn this off, we would have to watch for the "walking ants" and press Esc when we need to deactivate the copy mode.